# ¿Por qué el uso de % para mover una letra a un determinado número de lugares en una matriz hace que la matriz desaparezca?

Tags: c, matriz, encriptación, operador-resto-division

Quiero "encriptar" (es decir, ocultar de forma reversible) un string desplazando cada letra en un número determinado de lugares. Entonces intenté con 3:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string code;
    int i;
    code = get_string("Write your plaintext...\n");
    for(i=0;i<strlen(code);i++)
    {
        if (code[i]!=' '&code[i]!='!'&code[i]!='?'&code[i]!='.')
        {
        code[i]= ((code[i]+3)%26);

        //printf("%i%c\n",i,code[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", code);

}
```

Pero no me devuelve nada:

```
~/pset2/ $ ./caesar_hugues 
Write your plaintext...
Hello World!

~/pset2/ $
```

Por lo tanto cando solo hizo (code[i]+3) funciona pero no funciona para las letras al final del abcedario.

Comment: no entiendo para que sacas el modulo de la division con 26... sera eso? que da caracteres que no son letras?

Comment: La lógica del mod asume que las letras están entre el cero y el 26, no?

Comment: El algoritmo cifra los mensajes "rotando" cada letra ASCII por k posiciones @gbianchi . Más formalmente, si p es un texto plano (es decir, un mensaje sin cifrar), p_i es el carácter en i, y k es una clave secreta (es decir, un número entero no negativo), entonces cada letra c_i, en el texto cifrado c, se calcula como: (c_i = p_i +k)%26.  donde % aquí significa "resto al dividir por 26".

Comment: Si @Alfabravo . Por ejemplo Z (hasta que se traduce su codigo ASCII a las posiciones habituales) esta a la posicion 26. Si anado +3 obtenemos ] en la tabla de ASCII

Comment: NOPE. https://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: SI https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y6dh.png @Alfabravo

Comment: Por eso, el carácter `Z` tiene código ASCII 90, si le sumo 3 da 93, 93%26 = 15 y eso no da un carácter alfabético. Entonces, de nuevo, por qué asumes que los valores ASCII están entre 0 y 26?

Comment: deberias sumarle 65 para obtener caracteres imprimibles... tu logica de valores esta mal...

Comment: o hacer algo mucho mas simple.. sumar 3, y si es mayor a la Z, volver al inicio y sumar la diferencia...

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica tu vas a cifrar usando las mismas letras del alfabeto o vas a emplear tambien caracteres raros

Answer (score 0):

El método de cifrado que deseas implementar se conoce como el **cifrado César** o **cifrado por desplazamiento**. Es un tipo de cifrado por sustitución en el que una letra en el texto original es reemplazada por otra letra que se encuentra un número fijo de posiciones más adelante en el alfabeto. Es uno de los tipos de cifrados más antiguos, se dice que fue inventado por el emperador romano **Julio César** para proteger los mensajes que enviaba a sus generales durante las campañas militares. Se considera un método débil de criptografía, ya que es fácil decodificar el mensaje debido a sus técnicas de seguridad mínimas.

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int indiceDeCaracterEnCadena(char *cadena, char caracter)
{
    int indice = 0;

    while (cadena[indice] != '\0')
    {
        char actual = cadena[indice];
    
        if (actual == caracter)
        {
            return indice;
        }
    
        indice++;
    }

    return -1;
}

void concatenarCharACadena(char c, char *cadena)
{
    char cadenaTemporal[2];
    cadenaTemporal[0] = c;
    cadenaTemporal[1] = '\0';
    strcat(cadena, cadenaTemporal);
}

int main()
{
    int tamanoTexto = 100;
    char textoClaro[tamanoTexto];
    char alfabeto[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char textoCifrado[tamanoTexto];

    printf("Introduzca el texto a cifrar: ");
    fgets(textoClaro, tamanoTexto, stdin);

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(textoClaro) - 1; i++)
    {
        if(textoClaro[i] == ' ')
        {
            concatenarCharACadena(' ', textoCifrado);
        }
    
        if(textoClaro[i] != ' ' && textoClaro[i] != '!' && textoClaro[i] != '?' && textoClaro[i] != '.')
        {
            int pos = indiceDeCaracterEnCadena(alfabeto, textoClaro[i]);
            concatenarCharACadena(alfabeto[(pos + 3) % 26], textoCifrado);
        }
    }

    printf("%s", textoCifrado);
}
```

Primeramente se definen dos funciones:

**indiceDeCaracterEnCadena**: Se usa para devolver el índice que ocupa un caracter en el alfabeto de símbolos utilizados para cifrar que en este caso es el alfabeto del idioma español.

**concatenarCharACadena**: Se usa para concatenar un caracter a una cadena de caracteres.

Dentro del **método main** se declaran cuatro variables:

**tamanoTexto**: variable de tipo entero usada para guardar el tamaño de las cadenas de caracteres que se usan en el programa.

**textoClaro**: variable usada para guardar el texto a cifrar.

**alfabeto**: variable usada para almacenar el alfabeto usado para cifrar un texto, en este caso se usa el alfabeto del idioma español, pero podría ser cualquier otro alfabeto de símbolos.

**textoCifrado**: variable usada para guardar el texto ya cifrado.

Posteriormente se ejecuta un **ciclo for** que recorrerá todos los caracteres del texto que se quiere encriptar. Por cada caracter se busca el índice de posición que ocupa en la **variable alfabeto**, una vez que se tiene este índice se hace el  cifrado de ese caracter utilizando la fórmula **(pos + 3) % 26**, donde la **variable pos** guarda el índice del caracter que se va a cifrar, **+3** es el desplazamiento que se hará para cifrar, en este caso se cifra desplazando el caracter **3** posiciones en su alfabeto, es decir si se encuentra una **'a'** se cifraría como **'d'**, por último **%26** significa que si el desplazamiento rebasa la longitud del alfabeto no haya un desbordamiento al tratar de acceder a un índice que no existe en la **variable alfabeto**, por ejemplo si quisiéramos cifrar la **'z'** esta tendría el índice **25** y al hacer el desplazamiento tendríamos que **25 + 3 = 28**, que es mayor que la longitud del alfabeto que en este caso es **26**, por lo que ocurriría un error al intentar acceder a la posición **28** de la **variable alfabeto**, esto se corrige haciendo la operación de **resto de la división**, o sea **28 % 26 = 2**, de esta forma la **'z'** se cifraría como **'c'**.